# Highlight A Single Dynamic Table Row Background Color

Tags: php, css, dynamic

I am trying to figure out how to highlight one single row from a dynamic table using PHP or whatever needed to achieve this.
Basically I have a championship table and I want to highlight out the client's team from the others

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a if condition

```
if(client's team)
{
echo "<tr style='background-color:red'><td> data</td></tr>";
}
else{
    echo "<tr><td>data</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have tried that but that will just list the client's team...I want all the teams to be listed and the client's team to be highlighted from the rest